# The get method from two value its sending only one

Tags: php

I am trying to pass two values from one page to another page by URL re-writing but only one (Status) value is being sent. I am having difficulty in sending the second one (PropertyID). Please have a look at the code snippet below and suggest where am I going wrong.

### Code:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='activate.php?Status=Inactive&PropertyID='".$row['PropertyID']."''>Send Values</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Are u sure $row['PropertyID'] is actually having some value ?

Comment: ya i runed the query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are breaking the URL by closing the `href` to early.

It will work if you use:

`echo "<a href='activate.php?Status=Inactive&PropertyID=".$row['PropertyID']."'>Send Values</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

modify of your url

echo "Send Values";

second way

?>
& status=Inactive">Send Values

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this,

```
<?php
echo "<a href='activate.php?Status=Inactive&PropertyID=".$row['PropertyID']."'>Send Values</a>";
```

?>

Or you can also write it as below

```
echo "<a href='activate.php?Status=Inactive&PropertyID={$row['PropertyID']}'>Send Values</a>";
```